# iText - PDF file displaying message at the top about fillable form

Tags: pdf, itext, adobe-reader

Here is what I did:
1. I have a template WORD file that can be used to fill an application for some stuff. Assigned pre-defined tags to fillable fields.
2. Converted that word file to PDF file using CenoPdf
3. Used iText to fill the fields in generated PDF file.
4. Now when user downloads that filled file, they see a nice purple at the bar saying "Please fill out the following form. You can not save data typed into this form. Please print your completed form if you would like to copy for your records".

how can i get rid of this purple bar and the message? I am assuming i need to set some bits through iText to turn this off??

Thanks

Comment: I am considering to use iText for the same purpose - Word to fillable form. This states that users can't save partially filled forms using the free Acrobat Reader. Is this because Reader can't save filled results in any fillable form, or iText created forms can't save results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't edit the purple bar at the top. This is a flaw with Acrobat. Whenever your PDF contains form fields, the message is automatically displayed by force and you cannot edit it. Adobe feels that it's users are more important than it's developers, and forces the bar and message whenever form fields are present.